# Is Stack Exchange experimenting with KaTeX?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, technology, performance

[KaTeX](http://khan.github.io/KaTeX/) is a new TeX-to-web renderer that is supposed to be faster and more lightweight than MathJax.

Normally, I would just dismiss it as an interesting technology that might not be ready for production use yet.  However, the example at the bottom of that page…

[image: Animated screenshot comparing KaTeX and MathJax performance]

… caught my eye as something that looked [familiar](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/324158/77144)!

I think that compatibility might be a concern, though, both in terms of browser support and fidelity when rendering existing content.

Comment: They cherry-picked an answer on that page that actually renders with KaTeX. The more complex formulas on the same page (with various aligned environment) would not render with it. Sure, work takes less time if you don't  do a major part of it.